# jQuery css() of closest() returns undefined

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $drawer = $('.sc-drawer');

  $drawer.find( '.sc-drawer-dropdown' ).each( function () {
    var $this = $( this ),
        $dropdown = $this.closest('.sc-dropdown'),
        $height = $dropdown.css('height');
    console.log($height);
    });
});
```

```css
a {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sc-drawer">
  <a href="#" class="sc-drawer-dropdown">parent</a>
  <div class="sc-dropdown">
    <a href="/">Sub</a>
    <a href="/">Sub</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="sc-drawer-dropdown">parent</a>
  <div class="sc-dropdown">
    <a href="/">Sub</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In the example the sub elements are side by side but for me they are stacked/ underneath each other. 
So I would expect `$height` to be `92px` and `48px` but all I get is undefined.

How can I make it so that `$height` returns the expected result? I have also tried to use `$dropdown.height()` but that also returns `null`/ `undefined`

Comment: I know but `find()` also doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` traverses UP the DOM; try `.next()`. BTW, they'll both return the same height as they're inline elements. If they were block level you'd get X and 2X.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $drawer = $('.sc-drawer');

  $drawer.find('.sc-drawer-dropdown').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $dropdown = $this.next('.sc-dropdown'),
      $height = $dropdown.css('height');
    console.log($height);
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sc-drawer">
  <a href="#" class="sc-drawer-dropdown">parent</a>
  <div class="sc-dropdown">
    <a href="/">Sub</a>
    <a href="/">Sub</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="sc-drawer-dropdown">parent</a>
  <div class="sc-dropdown">
    <a href="/">Sub</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```